# How to scan an indefinite list of numbers from a single input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How to scan an indefinite list of numbers from a single input?

I did a brief google search and found hasNextInt(), but it only stops scanning if the last input is NOT an integer, while I need it to stop if it's the last integer. For example, it will continue to ask me if my list ends with an integer.

My code:

```
 System.out.println("Enter a list of numbers");
        int n = 0;
        while (input.hasNextInt()){
            n = input.nextInt();
            List.push(n);
        }
        List.displayStack();
```

Comment: Don't capitalize your variables. How do you want the user to notify your program that the list is over?

Comment: I want to make it so that the user only has to enter a list of ints (and not have to type out something like "a" at the end of the list to satisfy "hasNextInt.") Trying to find a way so that the program stops after reading the last int in the input, regardless of how many # of ints in the input.

Comment: You need some way of telling the program that no more ints are coming. You can close the standard input when you're done typing in ints. In eclipse, this is done with CTRL+Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `hasNext()` instead. Then parse the input and get the number -

```
    int n=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            //do something eg.- you have done
            //List.push(n);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
            //handle exception
        }
   }
```

Now if the input not is an integer then it will not stop. Rather it will go for the catch block. And since the catch block is still in the `while` loop so you can take a new input still now.

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot

Comment: This assumes the integers are separated by newlines. You'd also need a "break" in the catch block.